# How to apply a css class to master page based on the url using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I need to apply one css class based on the page i am in..All the divisions are in master page..

Can anyone help me with the code on how to find the url of the page and apply the class to that page using jquery?

Suppose this is my url how do i get just default.asp from it?

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Thanks.

Comment: Atleast post some pseudo code. That will be better that I need.... And its not my close vote

Comment: will you please add some code or jsfiddle

Comment: Why not adding the class on the server side?

Comment: How do i add it on server side??I need to apply css to <li> list..

Comment: Generate the menu items dynamically(_in a loop_) and check to see which url matches the current url. IMHO this is _server_'s task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the page name and then if it is specific page as per your requirement then you can add required css class on the fly:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      if (document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0] == 'index.aspx')
      {
          //Add CSS in page header
          $("head").append("<script> .my-css-class{ /* put style here */} <script/>");
      }    
    });
```

Comment: this is a really bad solution

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to set a css class in a container based on the current page.

**Method 1. Client side**

You can get the current url using

```
window.location.pathname;
```

Then you can use jQuery to set the class you want.

```
var targetElement = "#MyMainContainer";
if(someBusinessLogicHere){
    $(targetElement).addClass("myClass");
}
```

**Method 2. Server side**

Alternatively, you can add the class, in the server side, inside your view like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.MyClass = "MyMainContainer";
}
```

And use it in the master layout like this:

```
<div id=@ViewBag.MyClass>
    The content
</div>
```